# Azure - Virtual Machine Scale Sets Metric collection

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am wanting to collect machine metrics for instances within (overall would do aswell) Virtual Machines Scale Sets (VMSS) in a similar way to Virtual Machines Metrics through the **cli** using the command - az vm monitor metrics ([LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/monitor/metrics?view=azure-cli-latest)) - as the output for this is suitable for my usecase, I have not been able to find a solution for this and not sure where to look for such, as I can collect the VMSS instance names however they exist outside a resource group and inside the VMSS hence the above mentioned command does not work.

Sample CLI excract from the command `az vm monitor metrics` which I need from VMSS machienes

```
 "timeseries": [
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "average": 89.425,
              "count": null,
              "maximum": null,
              "minimum": null,
              "timeStamp": "2021-12-31T18:10:00+00:00",
              "total": null
            },...
```

Thank you

Edit : Added details

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, consider answering your question yourself, or accept an answer that solved your problem. Do not edit your question to include the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Microsoft does not provide an CLI command for retrieving metrics from the `az vm monitor` command, a workaround for this could be using the Python `MonitorManagmentClient`, using the `resource_id` as follows:

```
resource_id = (
        "subscriptions/{}/"                                     
        "resourceGroups/{}/"
        "providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachineScaleSets/{}"
    ).format(subscription_id, resource_group_name, vm_name)
```

This bit allows you to fetch metrics from `virtualMachineScaleSets` as needed.